Is there any way to flexibly change between VLM and LLM?
I want to train a VLM from LLM but when I inference, does the input have to contain image embedding and if I train with PEFT, will the other tasks of LLM be weakened?
My goal is that I want to keep the strengths of other tasks on LLM while it learns more about vision and when inferring the user can flexibly change between adding and not adding to the image. So is there a way?
Can I build something similar to BLIP2 but with an LLM of my own choosing?
I tried building a QFomer based layer with 2 images but the loss hardly decreases after each training, and I don't know where I'm going wrong.
This is my model:
from transformers import AutoImageProcessor, AutoModel
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, PreTrainedModel, PretrainedConfig


class SelfAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads):
        super(SelfAttention, self).__init__()
        self.self_attn = nn.MultiheadAttention(embed_dim, num_heads).to(torch.bfloat16)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.to(torch.bfloat16)
        attn_output, _ = self.self_attn(x, x, x)
        return attn_output

class CrossAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, query_dim, key_dim, hidden_dim, num_heads):
        super(CrossAttention, self).__init__()
        self.query_proj = nn.Linear(query_dim, hidden_dim).to(torch.bfloat16)
        self.key_proj = nn.Linear(key_dim, hidden_dim).to(torch.bfloat16)
        self.value_proj = nn.Linear(key_dim, hidden_dim).to(torch.bfloat16)
        self.multihead_attn = nn.MultiheadAttention(hidden_dim, num_heads).to(torch.bfloat16)
        self.output_proj = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, 1024).to(torch.bfloat16)
        
    def forward(self, query, key):
        query = query.to(torch.bfloat16)
        key = key.to(torch.bfloat16)
        value = self.value_proj(key)
        query = self.query_proj(query)
        key = self.key_proj(key)
        attn_output, _ = self.multihead_attn(query, key, value)
        output = self.output_proj(attn_output)
        return output
    
class QFormerLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, img_dim, hidden_dim, num_heads, feedforward_dim, text_dim):
        super(QFormerLayer, self).__init__()
        self.self_attn1 = SelfAttention(img_dim, num_heads)
        self.self_attn2 = SelfAttention(img_dim, num_heads)
        self.cross_attn_imgs = CrossAttention(img_dim, img_dim, hidden_dim, num_heads)
        self.cross_attn_text = CrossAttention(text_dim, img_dim, hidden_dim, num_heads)
        self.feedforward = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(img_dim, feedforward_dim).to(torch.bfloat16),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(feedforward_dim, img_dim).to(torch.bfloat16)
        )
        
    def forward(self, text, img1, img2):
        img1_attn = self.self_attn1(img1)
        img2_attn = self.self_attn2(img2)
        
        img_combined = self.cross_attn_imgs(img1_attn, img2_attn)
        cross_attn_output = self.cross_attn_text(text, img_combined)
        output = self.feedforward(cross_attn_output)
        return output, img1, img2

class QFormer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, img_dim, hidden_dim, num_heads, feedforward_dim, text_dim, num_layers):
        super(QFormer, self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([QFormerLayer(img_dim, hidden_dim, num_heads, feedforward_dim, text_dim) for _ in range(num_layers)])

    def forward(self, text, img1, img2):
        for layer in self.layers:
            output, img1, img2 = layer(text, img1, img2)
        return output

class PreTrainedModelForQFormer(PreTrainedModel):
    config_class = PretrainedConfig

    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.text_dim = config.text_dim
        self.img_dim = config.img_dim
        self.hidden_dim = config.hidden_dim
        self.num_heads = config.num_heads
        self.feedforward_dim = config.feedforward_dim
        self.num_layers = config.num_layers
        self.qformer = QFormer(self.img_dim, self.hidden_dim, self.num_heads, self.feedforward_dim, self.text_dim, self.num_layers)
        self.output_proj = nn.Linear(self.img_dim, 2048).to(torch.bfloat16)
        self.vs = AutoModel.from_pretrained(config.vision_model_name, trust_remote_code=True, torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16).to('cuda')
        self.vs1 = AutoModel.from_pretrained(config.vision_model_name, trust_remote_code=True, torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16).to('cuda')
        self.lm = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(config.lm_model_name).to(torch.bfloat16).to('cuda')
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(config.lm_model_name)
        for param in self.lm.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False
        for param in self.vs.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False
        for param in self.vs1.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = True

    def forward(self, text, img1, img2, label):
        img1 = img1.to(torch.bfloat16)
        img2 = img2.to(torch.bfloat16)
        text, labels, attn_mask = collate_fn(self.tokenizer, text, label, device="cuda")
        img1 = self.vs(img1).pooler_output
        img2 = self.vs1(img2).pooler_output
        qformer_output = self.qformer(text, img1, img2)
        qformer_output = self.output_proj(qformer_output)
        text_embeds = self.lm.get_input_embeddings()(text)
        inputs_embeds = torch.cat([qformer_output.unsqueeze(1), text_embeds], dim=1)
        labels = torch.cat([torch.full((labels.size(0), 1), -100, dtype=labels.dtype, device=labels.device), labels], dim=1)
        attn_mask = torch.cat([torch.ones((attn_mask.size(0), 1), dtype=attn_mask.dtype, device=attn_mask.device), attn_mask], dim=1)
        return self.lm(inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds, labels=labels, attention_mask=attn_mask)
    
    def save_pretrained(self, save_directory):
        torch.save(self.qformer.state_dict(), f"{save_directory}/qformer_weights.pth")
        torch.save(self.output_proj.state_dict(), f"{save_directory}/output_proj_weights.pth")

    @classmethod
    def from_pretrained(cls, config, load_directory):
        model = cls(config)
        model.qformer.load_state_dict(torch.load(f"{load_directory}/qformer_weights.pth", map_location=torch.device('cuda')))
        model.output_proj.load_state_dict(torch.load(f"{load_directory}/output_proj_weights.pth", map_location=torch.device('cuda')))
        return model

class QFormerConfig(PretrainedConfig):
    def __init__(self, text_dim=512, img_dim=2048, hidden_dim=512, num_heads=8, feedforward_dim=1024, num_layers=6, lm_model_name="google/gemma-1.1-2b-it", vs_model_name='OpenGVLab/InternViT-300M-448px', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text_dim = text_dim
        self.img_dim = img_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.feedforward_dim = feedforward_dim
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lm_model_name = lm_model_name
        self.vision_model_name = vs_model_name

text_dim = 512
img_dim = 1024
hidden_dim = 1024
num_heads = 8
feedforward_dim = 2048
num_layers = 1
lm_model_name = "google/gemma-1.1-2b-it"

